# How to debug react native App With chrome Browser?

Tags: react-native

I started react native app.But gives error like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When manually entering the IP address of your React Native Packager you also need to define the port number which is `8081`. In your case open the dev menu by either shaking the device or by long pressing the menu button and go to `Dev Settings` and then open `Debug server host & port for device`. There fill in your IP and then enter port number `8081`.

As from the screenshot I assume the value would be `192.168.0.107:8081`